# Getting views by ID defined on layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, findviewbyid

I'm doing my first Android project and is driving me kind of crazy. I'm developing an application that is going to work on tablets and smartphones of all resolutions. I have created a custom layout which right now fits perfect into the tablet, but when it goes to the smartphone it gets messy. So I asked google and found an interesting paper on how to scale views: http://www.vanteon.com/downloads/Scaling_Android_Apps_White_Paper.pdf

I have followed all the steps, but when i try to call

`scaleContents(View rootView, View container)`

I get an error telling me that my `IDs don't exist`.

This is my layout xml file (part of):

```
FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="1200px"
    android:layout_height="1700px"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    android:id="@+id/SussoClient"
```

And this is how I call the method:

```
LayoutScaler ls = new LayoutScaler();
ls.scaleContents(findViewById(android.R.id.content), findViewById(android.R.id.container));
```

It says `Cannot resolve symbol 'container'`, so, where should I define that ID in order to do this? of all the solutions I have tried to rescale the layout, this one looks the best.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the layout is your own then DONT use android.R.id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like vilpe89 said, change `android.R.id.content` to `R.id.content` and the R will be `your_package.R`which you have to import but not `import android.R"`

Comment: Ok, I feel stupid now!! That was easy. Thank you very much. Works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using LayoutScaler you should define all your dimensions in an xml file that is different for smartphones and tablets.

Comment: That means defining a lot of xml files since there's a lot of smartphones and tablets sizes and resolutions. This solution works perfect now

Comment: No one for smartphones and one for tablets

Comment: I tried that, and tried this app in a 7" and 10.1" tablets, and also on a 5.7" phablet. Since the layout background and all of its contents are custom images, it doesn't display well.

Comment: The custom images also need to be of different varients. I think xxhdpi is for tablets. I am not sure about that.

Comment: Yeah, that's right, or for devices with high resolution. I have finally left some of the values in px (images mostly) and some others in dp (buttons and text views)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `dp` instead of `px`. It is mentioned in the white paper you have shared and is also the way I prefer to use and it does not usually cause much harm on different screens.

Just give it a try and tell what happens.

Hope this helps !

Comment: Yes, I've tried. I don't see much difference, but I'm used to work with px, so I prefer the pixels.